# How to use generic type for functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers

I have some code which reads data from a queue . I want the function to be such that it takes a callback function as a parameter , the callback function basically contains code on what to do with the data that is extracted from the queue . The type for the getMessages fucntion is like so

```
getMessages ::  (ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad (Either Error Result)) -> KafkaMonad (Either Error ())
```

so the callback function needs to be always of the type

```
(ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad (Either Error Result))
```

although this code works I would like to have a more generic type for the get messages function ,something like

```
getmessages ::(ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad a) -> KafkaMonad (Either Error ())
or 
getMessages ::  f -> KafkaMonad (Either Error ())
```

When I try to use the mentioned Types ,like Kafkamonad a it throws me the error

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Either Error b0’ ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: 
getMessages :: forall a. Callback a -> KafkaMonad a at src/Kafka/Consume.hs:48:17 
Expected type: KafkaMonad (Either KafkaError b0) 
Actual type: KafkaMonad a
```

The related functions are as follows

```
type Callback a = ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> KafkaMonad a
getMessages ::  Callback a -> KafkaMonad a
getMessages callback = do
       let ....
       runHandler(Right kc)  = processMessages kc callback
    bracket mkConsumer clConsumer runHandler

processMessages :: Kc -> Callback a -> KafkaMonad a
processMessages k callback=     mapM_ (\_ -> do
                    ecr <- pollMessage k (Timeout 1000)
                    case ecr of
                      Right cr ->  do
                                   err <- commitAllOffsets OffsetCommit k
                                   case err of
                                        Nothing  -> callback cr
                                        Just err -> throwIO err 
                      Left err -> return $ Left $ KafkaError "Procesing Stopped"  

            ) [0 :: Integer .. ]
    return $ Right ()
```

What sort of Class constraints can I use to achieve this ? Or any other solution would be great too .

Comment: Why do you need a more generic type for the callback? In your use case, is there any specific difficulty with supplying a function that returns `Kafkamonad (Either Error Result)`?

Comment: I think you just want a type *alias*: `type CallbackType = ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad (Either Error Result)`. Then `getMessages :: CallbackType -> Kafkamonad (Either Error Result)`.

Comment: You may do this, your getmessages just needs to produce the `Either Error Result` itself since the callback no longer provides it.  Thus the callback no longer has control over whether an error is thrown or what result is produced. This may or may not be acceptable in your situation.

Comment: @duplode , So rigth now ,this works fine ,I was just anticipating for the the future , like maybe a case in which I need to write the records to a file . Maybe a return type of Kafkamonad ( Either FileError Bool)

Comment: @luqui I didnt quite understand the statement .

Comment: @chepner , No I basically need a generalised type for the Callback , I dont think a type declaration would be able to help me with that ?

Comment: Well, how is it supposed to be generalized? What specific examples *other* than `ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad (Either Error Result)` do you have in mind? `type Callback a = ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad a` would seem to allow `a` to be either `Either Error Result` or `Either FileError Bool`.

Comment: @chepner ,That is What I want to do , have the type as onsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (Maybe ByteString) -> Kafkamonad a , But if I keep this it gives me an error ,so I was just wondering is there a class constraint I can add to resolve this ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a type alias parameterized over the type wrapped by `Kafkamonad`:

```
type CallbackType a = ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (MaybeByteString) -> Kafkamonad a
```

Then you can define `getMesagages` using this type as well.

```
getMessages :: CallbackType a -> KafkaMonad (Either Error ())
```

Note that this type annotation dictates what the definition of `getMessages` can be; you can't make *any* assumptions about what `a` might be. If there are any restrictions (imposed by `Kafkamonad` or by a required definition of `getMessages`), you'll need to specify those in your question.

Based on your error message, you have unstated assumptions about what what type is wrapped by `Kafkamonad` which prevents your from fully parameterizing the callback type. Try

```
type CallbackType a = ConsumerRecord (Maybe ByteString) (MaybeByteString) -> Kafkamonad (Either KafkaError a)
```

or modify your definition to remove the assumptions.

Comment: this is what i am getting 
Error: • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Either Error b0’ ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: getMessages :: forall a. Callback a -> KafkaMonad a at src/Kafka/Consume.hs:48:17 
Expected type: KafkaMonad (Either KafkaError b0) 
Actual type: KafkaMonad a If this isn't sufficient let me know , I will try to add the code for the specific functions in the contex

Comment: added some of the details to the question.